# What is the difference between FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL and 0?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, file-io

What is the difference between passing the `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL` (0x80) and 0 to CreateFile function?

Comment: @John: I don't think it's a duplicate of that. That question asks what `0` does. This question asks what the difference is between using `0` and `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL`. (Which isn't answered by the answers there.)

Comment: I'd actually be interested to know **why** there is a `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL` at all (i.e. why have a flag meaning "no flags set" when that's what 0 would do). Presumably historical but I can't find anything that explains it.

Comment: If it is historical and nobody know the reason then I'd like to read Raymond Chen blog post about it. Could someone ask him to write? :)

Comment: The best way to make Raymond Chen not blog about something is to ask him to blog about it :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the MSDN page for CreateFile():

> Note  When CreateFile opens an existing file, it generally combines the file flags with the file attributes of the existing file, and ignores any file attributes supplied as part of dwFlagsAndAttributes.

Or to put it another way, you want a value that means "I don't care" when you open an existing file.  Because the operating system doesn't care.  That value is 0.

Comment: So if you pass FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL instead, wouldn't that also mean "I don't care"? And what about creation of a new file, would it matter there?

Answer (score 2):

`FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL` explicitly sets no attributes. If you pass 0, the set of attributes is unspecified.